# NASM x64 Linux movsb segfaults

Tags: nasm

I'm trying to recreate the strcpy function in asm, the thing is when I use movsb to move a byte from rsi to rdi my program segfaults, I'm not sure if movsb is the right thing to use here, I'm just beginning to learn assembly, here is the code:

```
global ft_strcpy

section .text:
ft_strcpy:
    mov rcx, 0
    jmp copy

copy:
    inc rcx
    cmp BYTE[rsi], 0
    je  exit
    cld
    movsb
    jmp copy

exit:
    movsb
    sub rdi, rcx
    mov rax, rdi
    ret
```

and here's a simple main to test it

```
char    *ft_strcpy(char *d, char *s);

int     main(void)
{
    char *s = "hello";
    char *d = "world!!!!";

    ft_strcpy(d, s); //it crashes here and with lldb it says it's at movsb
    return (0);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It would be more useful to have a [mcve], the problem may be outside this code and we don’t know what edi or esi point to etc

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I edited my post and added a main to test it

Comment: Your pointers point to string literals, which are in read only memory. Therefore you can’t write to them and that causes a segfault. If you switch to `char d[] = “something”;` then it would allocate a separate writable memory block, or just allocate a block of memory as usual.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks ! I totally forgot about that so it was just my main x)